# Why I can't connect to rds db from my machine

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, amazon-vpc

I have created postgres db with aws rds but can't connect to it. I googled it, and found similar questions but any answer helped. Most of problem was because of security group configuration, but I've allowed all traffic and it didn't help.

My db settings:[image]

and I checked is 5432 port is opened for me with this site http://portquiz.net/.
also tried to ping that endpoint, it doesn't response.

Please, help me.

**UPD: additional settings screenshots.**

I use default settings for new aws account. So, as I can see - db exists in default VPC with 3 subnets (1 for each AZ). Every subnet uses the same ACL and route table.

ACL settings:
[image: ACL settings]

RouteTable settings
[image]
[image]

And VPC has InternetGateway with next settings:
[image]

**UPD: solved**

As I said in comments - aws sent me an email after few hours 'Your request has been confirmed to be available in the following AWS regions' and everything started to work. So, maybe you should wait some time if nothing helps.

Comment: i remember when i was developing rds, i have an EC2 to rdp and connect to rds from there. there are ways around it if you want to connect from outside the VPC but not straight forward.

Comment: When you say you can't connect to it, do you mean you can't connect to it locally from your computer?

Comment: @GreenyMcDuff, yes

Comment: Do you have an internet gateway that is route-able from the subnet that this RDS instance resides in?

Comment: @GreenyMcDuff, yes, I have updated question and added screenshots. Check it please

Comment: Thanks, for the vpc route table can you show which subnets it's associated to please

Comment: @GreenyMcDuff, done

Comment: and one more thing - few minutes ago I created ec2 instance with security-group: allow inbound ssh and outbound all trafic. In `subnet-3d543467` subnet. Connected via ssh and run `ping database-1.cnjuip7pds04.eu-west-1.rds.amazonaws.com`, after few second I stopped it and saw next output: `2 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 1026ms`. 


So, for some reason I can't connect to my rds from ec2 too...

Comment: I am able to connect to your database, but it says: "password authentication failed for user "master"`. If you are unable to connect, then the problem is probably with your network. Try connecting from a different network, such as home vs office, or even tethered via your phone.

Comment: @John Rotenstein, thank you for help. It is a little bit stupid but 15hours ago in the middle of the night I got email from AWS ''You recently requested access to AWS, which required additional verification. Your request has been confirmed to be available in the following AWS regions: Europe (Ireland).". And after that everything started to work. It is pity, because I spent the whole day and didn't know that they were checking me =(

Comment: Feel free to delete this Question if you don't think it will aide people in future.

Comment: I believe it can help somebody